# Android SQLite Transaction with database is locked

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am very new to the world of android. Here is what I am trying to accomplish. So I want to make a simple calibration session for the accelerometer sensor, which simply collect the accelerometer data and insert them into the database in a period of 3 minutes.
Here are my codes:

**Calibration Activity**

```
package com.example.calibration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.calibration.AccelsService.LocalBinder;


public class CalibrationActivity extends Activity{
    private final String DEBUG_TAG = CalibrationActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView mCountdownTv;
    private Button mStartButton;
    private final int countdownPeriod = 10; //3 Minutes

    private AccelsService mService;
    private boolean mBound;

    private Intent mIntent;

    private class myCountdown extends CountDownTimer{
        public myCountdown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int minutes = (int) millisUntilFinished / (60*1000);
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished - minutes*60*1000)/1000;
            if (seconds >= 10){
                mCountdownTv.setText(minutes+":" + seconds);    
            }
            else{
                mCountdownTv.setText(minutes+":0" + seconds);
            }
         }
         public void onFinish() {
            mCountdownTv.setText("Done!");
            mCountdown = null;
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Done Calibrating! With mBound = "+mBound);
            if (mBound){
                mService.setTransactionStatus(true);
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mBound = false;
            }
            mStartButton.setEnabled(true); 
         }  
    }

    private CountDownTimer mCountdown;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder iservice) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) iservice;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calibration);

        mCountdownTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown_timer);
        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mIntent = new Intent(CalibrationActivity.this, AccelsService.class);        
                bindService(mIntent,mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                //Start to countdown 3 minutes and stop the service
                if (mCountdown==null){
                    mCountdown = new myCountdown(1000*countdownPeriod, 1000);
                    mCountdown.start();
                }
                //Disable the button after it's clicked
                mStartButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"ONSTOP! mBound is "+mBound);
        if (mBound) {
            mService.setTransactionStatus(false);
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calibration, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AccelsService:**

```
package com.example.calibration;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AccelsService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{
    private final String DEBUG_TAG = AccelsService.class.getSimpleName();

    private boolean mTransactionStatus = false;//Indicate if the service should commit the database changes
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        AccelsService getService() {
            // Return this instance of AccelsService so clients can call public methods
            return AccelsService.this;
        }
    };

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    private AccelsDbHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onStartCommand!" );
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        startCalibration();
        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(AccelsService.this);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "AccelService got Destroyed!" );
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSensorChanged" );
        new AccelTask().execute(event);
    }
    private class AccelTask extends AsyncTask<SensorEvent,Void,Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(SensorEvent... events){
            mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ AccelsDbHelper.ACCELS_TABLE_NAME +" VALUES ( "+ events[0].values[0]
                    +", "+ events[0].values[1] + ", " + events[0].values[2] + ", " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " );");
            return null;
        }
    }
    private void startCalibration(){
        /*Register the Sensor Listener */
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = (Sensor) mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Toast.makeText(this, "AccelService starting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mDbHelper = new AccelsDbHelper(this);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        mDb.beginTransaction();
        if (mTransactionStatus){
            try{
                mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }
            finally{
                mDb.endTransaction();
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTransactionStatus(boolean isSuccessful){
        mTransactionStatus = isSuccessful;
    }

}
```

I have omitted the SQLiteOpenHelper class, because it's pretty much ordinary. So after clicking on the button, the OnSensorChanged() event keeps getting called, and no error occur at this stage. Nonetheless, I don't think the data is getting written to the database at all, because I cannot see any data generated from the DDMS view on Eclipse. Then, after the code is done, I tried to click on the button again. But now I am getting the error "(5) database is locked". I am so confused. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: As there is async task in your app, It will try to access db while one process with db is going on. So it may fire error like db locked as still it is busy with some process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
mDb.beginTransaction();
if (mTransactionStatus){
    try{
        mDb.setTransactionSuccessful()
    }
    finally{
        mDb.endTransaction();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like you close the transaction unless mTransactionStatus is true.